# Why am I getting "run-time error 438" using dialog box to insert pic with vba-word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using word macro to insert some pictures with the dialog box. 
while I am trying out this I am getting a runtime error 438 - object doesn't support this property or ... 
even with this problem, I am able to insert the picture. But also wondered the reason why I can not call this macro in another macro.
Could anyone help with this?

I deleted unnecessary code that I have previously. but It seems like I still have some function that does not exist or necessary?

```
Sub Insert_Diagram()
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim oDialog As Word.Dialog
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim mg1 As Range
Dim mg2 As Range

Set oDialog = Dialogs(wdDialogInsertPicture)

With oDialog

    If .Show = -1 Then
        For Each vItem In .SelectedItems
            Set mg2 = ActiveDocument.Range
            mg2.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture _
              FileName:=vItem, _
              LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=mg2
            Set mg1 = ActiveDocument.Range
            mg1.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

        Next vItem
    End If
End With; End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the error happening? Is this within the WKBK module?

Comment: yes, this is an independent module. I don't see any cursor indicating the place that the error occurred ..:(

Comment: Perhaps step through the code using `F8` and try to figure it out? maybe your `If` statement is never returning `True`.

Comment: oh.. It seems so, thanks! I after If condition it gives me the error, I  will try again

Comment: SelectedItems is not a property of Dialogs. It is a property of FileDialogs. I suggest you review the Office VBA Referenc.